# Why Code::Blocks won't start anymore after pc reboot

Tags: codeblocks, windows-7-x64

I've looked for someone with my same problem but it seems nobody had this drawback with Code::blocks. I've installed the 20.03 version and after the installation it works fine, also if i close and reopen C::B it works fine but if i restart my pc, then it won't open anymore. It stucks at the splash screen with the C::B title and version and nothing else appens. In the task manager i see that it use only 15.000/24.000kb of ram (over 70.000 when it works), I'm using windows 7-64 bit.
It's a problem if i have installed it in the secondary hdd? MinGW is in the same hdd.
I'm here for any other axplanation, thank you guys